# GHC try-catch for runStmt/exprType

Tags: haskell, exception, ghc, ghci

`GHC` monad is an instance of `ExceptionMonad` and there are the two actions `runStmt` and `exprType` that interest me currently. Should one pass an invalid argument (e.g. an undefined symbol, syntactically incorrect string ...) any of the two would raise an exception, effectively terminating the session (in interpreter mode). How could one wrap these functions so that they always succeed, but produce a `Maybe` or `Either` result to account for exceptions? One thing I don't understand is, why does `runStmt` also throw an exception when it already supports returning one in its return value. For `exprType` I am seeking something like

```
exprType' :: GhcMonad m => String -> m (Maybe Type)
exprType' e = (fmap Just $ exprType e) `catch` (const $ return Nothing)
```

I am currently using GHC 7.10.2, and I am really confused with all `Either`/`Error`/... implementations of exceptional behaviour, so I do not have any piece of code that would be anywhere close to my goal :(.

---

The closest I got is (I try to convert the `Either` further to a single string, which should not be important):

```
typeOf :: String -> Ghc String
typeOf e = do
    r <- gtry (exprType e)
    return . either (const "err") (showSDocUnsafe . ppr) $ r
```

but then ghc complains:

```
No instance for (Exception b0) arising from a use of ‘gtry’
The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Exception ArithException -- Defined in ‘GHC.Exception’
  instance Exception ErrorCall -- Defined in ‘GHC.Exception’
  instance Exception SomeException -- Defined in ‘GHC.Exception’
  ...plus two others
In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘gtry (exprType e)’
In the expression:
  gtry (exprType e)
  >>= return . either (const "err") (showSDocUnsafe . ppr)
In an equation for ‘typeOf’:
    typeOf e
      = gtry (exprType e)
        >>= return . either (const "err") (showSDocUnsafe . ppr)
```

Comment: `Control.Exception.try` seems to do exactly what you want. Namely "How could one wrap these functions so that they always succeed, but produce a Maybe or Either result to account for exceptions?". The `RunException` constructor is for when *executing* the statement produces an exception, ie, this is an exception propagated from the executed code.

Comment: But doesn't `Control.Exception.try` work just in `IO` not any arbitrary `MonadIO`? Here I am in the context of `GhcMonad` (or `GHC`).

Comment: My mistake, you'll have to use `Exception.gtry  :: (ExceptionMonad m, Exception e) => m a -> m (Either e a)`. It is the same thing but for the GHC `ExceptionMonad` interface.

Comment: You have to specify what exception you are catching. You could do `r :: Either SomeException _ <- gtry (exprType a)`. Although catching `SomeException` is considered bad practice.

Comment: Is there a proper way? Btw thanks, at least I have a working backup solution ;).

Comment: Yes, simply catch the particular exception you are interested in. `SomeException` will include exceptions due to things like IO errors (like a disk failure). You probably want these to be propagated so that the program does crash.

Comment: Well maybe I am not bright enough, but I find the documentation very bad (some "public" functions do not have a single comment) and I really don't know what exceptions are allowed to leave `runStmt` or `exprType` or any other function.